# How to set dynamic camera position for viewing 3d model in libgdx?

Tags: 3d, libgdx

Currently I am trying to make simple 3d model viewer in libgdx. I am just curious if I can change camera to view 3d model correctly.

//--- 3d model part

```
 Model smallCar= assets.get("data/small_car.obj", Model.class);//<--dynamic model
 ModelInstance smallCarInstance = new ModelInstance(smallCar);
```

I can set static position of camera but I want to set camera position far from car according to size of car model like below :

```
cam.position.set(1f, 1f, smallCar.getWidth()* 2f); //<--isn't available
cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
```

The camera position should be dynamic so that it's position don't effect the view of 3d model. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BoundingBox boundingBox = smallCarInstance.calculateBoundingBox(new BoundingBox());
float maxDistance = Float.max(Float.max(boundingBox.getWidth(), boundingBox.getHeight()), boundingBox.getDepth());
cam.position.set(0f, 0f, maxDistance * 2f);
cam.lookAt(0f, 0f, 0f);
cam.rotateAround(Vector3.Zero, Vector3.X, -30f);
cam.update();
```

Comment: thanks for help bro. 
That above code is giving me black screen. When i print boundingBox values. I get 
   width: 209.93173 height: 154.37787 depth : 360.4398

Without using above code, if I zoom out camera to show the car properly. Then at perfect position, camera's z value is -94. 

I don't need position to be exactly twice of 3d model's width. I just need camera to show the model properly. So, any idea why may not above code be working?

Comment: Ok, Finally I get it to work. Above code from @Kappa is working correctly. The problem was clipping plane was set to 100 and 3d model was bigger in size. I just had to reset clipping plane before cam.update for visibility of bigger 3d model. 
     cam.far = maxDistance * 5;